# How can I create a searchbar in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code to display a searchbar, it works and displays properly. However whenever I select it to initiate typing, it never does anything and doesn't allow me to type anything in there. How can I fix this?

```
struct SearchBar: View {

@Binding var text: String

var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center)  {
        TextField("Search", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
           
        })
          
            .padding(.leading, 8)
            .background(Color(.gray))
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]. This likely depends on what you are using for the `Binding`. Are you using a `.constant`?

Answer (score 0):

If the text variable is only used within the `SearchBar` View, using a `@State` variable within the `SearchBar` View instead of a `@Binding` would allow the view to manage the state of the `TextField` directly, without relying on a `@Binding` from a **parent View**.
This could make the code simpler and easier to understand, but this probably isn't your case.

In the provided code, the `TextField` is using a `@Binding` to get the value of the `TextField`, which you are probably passing down from a **parent View**.
You should check the value you are injecting when instatiating the `SearchBar` View. Probably you are passing a `.constant()` to it, and this is why you aren't able to edit the text on it.

To fix this, you would need to create a `@State` variable on the **parent View** and pass it to the **child View** instead of a `.constant()`.

Here is an example of the **Parent View**:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildView(text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the **Child View**:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Your title here", text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example will not compile as it is.

Comment: Your edits fixed them.